# Splitting $CO_2$ as a plasma to remove it from the atmosphere

Tags: atmospheric-science, plasma-physics

I am wondering if CO2 can be removed from the atmosphere by heating it up using the same lasers they use to make plasma when researching nuclear fusion, and then fire the plasma of oxygen and carbon through a magnetic field to separate the atoms before they recombine together.

**Thanks for all of the answers.**  So for CO2, plants are the most efficient way of doing this.  I have a supplemental question.  Why can't plasma lasers + magnetic separation be used to get rid of stuff that is currently buried in landfill or incinerated?  For example, asbestos and biotech waste.  Build a site in northern Africa with a vast array of solar panels, and use the energy to reduce this stuff to its elements.

Here is a link to another question about plasma recycling:

[A question about the properties of plasma and its potential use in recycling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/448826/a-question-about-the-properties-of-plasma-and-its-potential-use-in-recycling)

Comment: And where, pray tell, would the energy to make the plasma come from?

Comment: And, of course, the accelerating potential to actually extract the ions from the plasma, give them some velocity, and then send them through a magnetic field?

Comment: Perhaps a more useful question would be: does (high-energy) radiation from the sun combined with the earth's magnetic field appreciably disassociate and remove CO2 from the atmosphere? I'm guessing no

Comment: Seems like there are two separate issues here: **(1)** if this is physically viable; **(2)** if it'd be economically practical.

Comment: To note it, the problem of capturing $\mathrm{CO}_2$ from the atmosphere has been solved for over 100 years now; technologies to do this were well-established by the early 1900's.  These technologies would make an easy solution to concerns about the greenhouse effect altering our climate **_if_** they weren't so energetically unfavorable at that scale.  So, you can come up with all sorts of physically viable tactics for removing $\mathrm{CO}_2 ,$ but the ultimate issue is going to be if they can be practically implemented at a global scale.

Comment: It would be best to ask the supplementary question as a new question I think.

Comment: Regarding the update, you might want to instead post a new question asking how much energy it'd take to process an ordinary bag of garbage using this technique.  Ya know, to get an estimate for how many solar arrays it'd take.

Comment: You might want to read up about the Calutrons at Oak Ridge during the Manhattan Project. Yes, they separated all the U-235 for Little Boy (although did not do all the enrichment from natural occurrence), but it took them quite some time and quite a lot of electricity (there is a reason the facility was built near TVA). Now, C and O are a bit easier to mass separate, but still...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of the process, conservation of energy implies that it takes at least as much energy to convert $\mathrm{CO_2}$ back into carbon & oxygen as you originally got from burning the carbon, so unless you have *lots* of cheap carbon-neutral energy at your disposal, this is a losing proposition.

So at this stage of the game, we let plants perform the conversion, using chlorophyll and free solar energy.

There *are* groups investigating various ways to split $\mathrm{CO_2}$; several of these split it to oxygen and $\mathrm{CO}$, but here's one, slightly similar to your proposal, that goes all the way to oxygen and carbon: [An investigation of $\mathrm{CO_2}$ splitting using nanosecond pulsed corona discharge: effect of argon addition on $\mathrm{CO_2}$ conversion and energy efficiency](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6595/aa5b1d). But as I said above, these schemes are only useful if the energy they require is from carbon neutral sources.

Comment: PM2Ring, using cheap carbon neutral energy to "split" atmospheric CO2, at 400 ppm, is a losing proposition under any circumstances.  If you had that energy source, you would want to use it to displace a process that is currently burning fossil fuel, and let green plants absorb the atmospheric CO2.

Comment: @David I agree with you. It's rather pointless using carbon-neutral energy to split atmospheric $\mathrm{CO_2}$ if you can use that green energy to instead displace a process that's burning fossil fuel. Even using green splitting tech on concentrated $\mathrm{CO_2}$, eg directly on the exhaust of a gas-burning power station, is a dubious proposition.

Comment: PM2Ring, I agree.  I have a chemical engineering background, and the one thing that I know for sure is that every chemical process operates at less than 100% efficiency.  For simple, one step processes (e.g., a pump with an electric driver on it), the typical overall efficiency is in the 70% range.  If you have a 2 step process, you are down to 49% efficiency, etc.  This means that you want to minimize the number of energy conversion steps in order to maximize efficiency of the process.

Comment: As long as we're using large $\mathrm{CO}_2$-emitters, e.g. coal-fired power plants, our best strategy to offset emissions (besides ridding ourselves of the emitters) is to attach a carbon-capture unit to them.  This is energetically favorable over open-air capture since the flue gas from point-sources has a much higher concentration of $\mathrm{CO}_2$ than the atmosphere.  At current, it reduces a power-plant's effective output by about $30 \% ,$ assuming that the power plant sustains its own capture unit.

Comment: @Nat Fair point, but of course carbon dioxide *capture* is cheaper (in terms of energy) than actually splitting the carbon dioxide to carbon & oxygen.

Comment: Yeah, I figure that capture's the goal (given the title).  I get the impression that they saw some sort of video about ionization and then magnetic separation, and they're curious if this can be applied to the problem of carbon capture.  I suspect that they see the separated carbon- and oxygen-streams as waste to be dealt with.

Comment: @DavidWhite: I think there's a case where it could be useful: imagine we've suddenly found some zero-carbon source of *lots* of energy,  But there's already enough CO2 in the atmosphere that we're in really bad trouble, and plants won't scrub it fast enough.  So we could then use our zero-carbon energy (of which we have, by assumption, enough to replace all the carbon-producing energy as well as this) to aggressively scrub CO2 to limit the climate excursion we would otherwise experience.  This isn't a plausible scenario short of really cheap fusion poer or something.

Comment: @tfb, the CO2 IR absorption band is already saturated, and has been saturated since approximately 20-40 ppm.  The IR absorption band can be broadened a bit, but it takes a LOT more CO2 to get a substantial broadening.  This means that we will NOT find that suddenly, there is a huge issue.  It also means that there will be time to use nuclear energy to go "carbon free" such that we let a slowly developing problem turn into a slowly developing solution.

Comment: @DavidWhite: If you think that's true then presumably you also think that man-made CO2 emissions don't matter since we're so far above 40ppm.  If you think that, then, well, OK: publish!