# Plasma From Metals

Tags: plasma-physics

Is it possible to create a dense gaseous plasma from Metals like aluminium, iron etc... using things like Z Pinches? If yes, what would be the efficiency of the process?

In a cylindrical array Z pinch you have a ~10-50MA pulse lasting for 100ns through an array of copper wires parallel to the glass enclosure containing the plasma.

This produces a corresponding time-varying azimuthal B-Field, and by Faraday’s law giving an E-Field in the order of ~ 10^12 V/m more or less depending on the position inside the pinch. As far as I understand this is more than enough to breakdown any material, however, would this produce “single ions,” as opposed to “clusters” or “fragments” of ions?

Comment: What does "efficiency" mean in this context?

Comment: See wiki on [Vacuum arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_arc)

Comment: By efficiency I mean the amount of input energy compared to the total of ionization energy of each individual atom.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/448936/59023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a plasma out of a submillimeter liquid tin droplet by firing a multi kW CO2 laser pulse on it. This is how EUV (13.5 nm) light is produced in the latest generation of lithographic tools for the semiconductor industry.